# Conversion Swift2 -> Swift3: Errors with Any

Tags: swift3, any

I'm using CustomCollectionViewLayout from https://github.com/brightec/CustomCollectionViewLayout.

After the conversion from Swift2 to Swift3 two errors regarding Any occurs.

Error1:

```
override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    return self.itemAttributes[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
}
```

Message error:

> CustomCollectionViewLayout.swift:115:54: Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Error 2:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    if self.itemAttributes != nil {
        for section in self.itemAttributes {

            let filteredArray  =  (section as AnyObject).filtered(

                using: NSPredicate(block: { (evaluatedObject, bindings) -> Bool in
                    return rect.intersects(evaluatedObject.frame)
                })
                ) as! [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]


            attributes.append(contentsOf: filteredArray)

        }
    }

    return attributes
}
```

Message Error:

> Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'frame'

Any ideas how to fix the Problems with Any/AnyObject?

Comment: I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

I solved the errors, replace your both the methods to below ones

```
override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        //return self.itemAttributes[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
        let arr = self.itemAttributes[indexPath.section] as! NSMutableArray
        return arr[indexPath.row] as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
    }


override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        if self.itemAttributes != nil {
            for section in self.itemAttributes {

                let filteredArray  =  (section as! NSMutableArray).filtered(

                    using: NSPredicate(block: { (evaluatedObject , bindings) -> Bool in
                        let a = evaluatedObject as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
                        return rect.intersects(a.frame)
                    })
                    ) as! [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]


                attributes.append(contentsOf: filteredArray)

            }
        }

        return attributes
    }
```